# What is python .get() method is doing in this scenario?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I was going through a tutorial for list data scraping from a web page and wehave a BeautifulSoup object named 'soup', I am supposed to find all the elements from 'soup' such that they are in a table and the element is in some class so they did this:

```
> [t["class"] for t in soup.find_all("table") if t.get("class")]
```

so I don't understand 2 things here, what is `t["class"]` doing in here why didn't we simply write `t` since the if condition is applied on the right why do we need to do `t["class"]` in the first place.

and why are we using .get() method as boolean in this case, I mean does it not return the value stored for a key in a dictionary?

Does it mean the beautiful soup object is a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "what is t["class"] doing in here why didn't we simply write t"*

Obviously because the author wanted to retrieve the `class` attribute of the tag, not the full tag.

> why are we using .get() method as boolean in this case, I mean does it not return the value stored for a key in a dictionary?

`dict.get(key[, default=None])` does indeed return the value for key `key` if it's set or `default` (which defaults to `None`) if it isn't.

The goal here is obviously to only get `class` for tags having one.

> Does it mean the beautiful soup object is a dictionary?

Here 't' is not "the beautiful soup object', it's a `Tag` instance. And while not strictly being a `dict`, it does behave as a one wrt/ html attributes indeed. This is documented FWIW.

Comment: Since we are already doing `t["class"]` that is basically retrieving `class` attribute of the tag why do we need to use `if t.get("class")` at the end?

Comment: For tags without a "class" attributes, `t['class"]` would raise a `KeyError` - but since the condition is evaled before, it protects us from this (`t["class"] won't be executed if `t.get("class")` returns a falsy value). See Adam Smith's answer for alternatives way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get` returns the value associated with the key it's given, or `None`. As an example:

```
>>> foo = {'spam': 'eggs'}
>>> foo.get('spam')
'eggs'
>>> foo['spam']
'eggs'
>>> foo.get('bar')
None
>>> foo['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bar'
```

I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup, so it might be necessary in this case to do something like this, but typically you'd just check for membership before including

```
[t['class'] for t in soup.find_all('table') if 'class' in t]
```

Or more rarely use `dict.get` in the selector and filter out the `None` objects afterwards

```
tmp = [t.get('class') for t in soup.find_all('table')]
result = filter(tmp, None)
# this is equivalent to:
# result = [v for v in tmp if v]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is an example of your tutorial, you probably wan't to get the text, not the class

I will write the list compreheision as "for" format:

```
result = []
tables = soup.find_all("table")
for t in tables:
    if t.get("class"): #Check if tables have class attribute
        result.append(t["class"]) #Probably you don't wan't the class name of the table, maybe you wan't the text
```